# is it possible to lookup a cell value and populate a drop down box with the results in a separate cell

Tags: google-sheets, drop-down-menu, vlookup

I have a google sheet with all current staff information.  I have a second sheet for when some piece of data needs changed.  Last name, Location, job ect.

on second sheet I am looking to have someone:

```
  Enter the user's first name in column B, 
  and or Last name in Column C,
```

I would like a drop down box generated in column D from the given info to contain all usernames found in the sheet with current information for all staff that have the given first and or last names provided.

Once a username has been selected, I can get all the pertinent data from that user with a vlookup from the sheet containing all staff info.  For example if someone typed Scott in column B, I would like a drop down generated in column D with all staff that have a first name of Scott.  Likewise if the last name was supplied and of course if both first and last was supplied.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: You can use `INDIRECT()` function to create that, if you share copy of sheet with what you want to achieve it will help

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jZciJzvWq-FUiA3znPLNiSDAv9iZF5em3ZnWxf9VZWc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation need to be done that's it,

1) Go to `Staff Changes'!B2` and `Data Validation> List from range` & choose range from `'Staff Info'!B2:B`

2) Select cell`'Staff Changes'!D2` and  `Data Validation> List from range` & range will be filter formula i.e `'Staffing Changes'N2:N`.

**Result**

[image: result2] [image: result1]

Few tweaks in vlookup:
I am not sure if you need username column twice if you don't need then change your vlookup formula from `=vlookup(D2,'Staff Info'!A:K,10,0)` to `=VLOOKUP(D2,'Staff Info'!$G$1:$K,2,0)`

Please provide access to trix in future so that changes & result can be shown in it.

**UPDATE:**

Use data validation as before & hide filter colum or use seperate sheet for filter formula & use query function in cell A3 `=QUERY('Staff Info'!A:J,"select ' ',A,F,'  ','   ',G,'    ',I,'     'where A='"&A2&"' AND F = '"&B2&"' LABEL ' ''Date','  ''Current Last Name','   ''New Last Name','    ''New Building','     ''New Classification'",1)` result wil be something like this
[image]

[QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

Comment: Unfamiliar with Trix or how to provide access.  I have modified sheet to show problems I am having.  Column B, C, (selection from D), E, G, I will be typed in by HR secretary. You can see when I copy formulas to new row problems occur in Column N which results in problems in D as well.  Formulas copied to first 8 rows at this point.  Will eventually be 1000 rows.  New sheet started each new school year. Staff info will continue to grow  as ALL employees past and present need to be in list since usernames can NEVER be reused.

Comment: There might be an other way to overcome your problem but i tried with what i know , i have updated the answer

Comment: This works using the top as a username lookup.  Is there a way to clear the username when the first name is cleared?  I tried a script as follows but it does not do anything.

Comment: var SHEET = "Staff Changes";

var COLUMN_NUMBER = 1
 
function onEdit(A) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  //Ensure on correct sheet.
  if(SHEET == activeSheet.getName()){
    var cell = ss.getActiveCell()
    var cellValue = cell.getValue();
    
    //Ensure we are looking at the correct column.
    if(cell.getColumn() == COLUMN_NUMBER){
      //If the cell matched the value we require,hide the row. 
      if(cellValue == ""){
        sheet.getRange('B6:B6').clearContent();
      };
    };
  };
}

Comment: ('B6:B6') should really be ('B3:B3')

Comment: Script is bit incorrect i believe its bit hard to read, Please provide access  https://support.google.com/docs/thread/11414824?hl=en to sheet or raise new question with your code

Comment: I figured it out.  Thank you for all your help.  I found a mis-spelling in my code (case sensitive) which fixed the clear  code up.